# Enumere los números que aún no han sido sorteados

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo un sistema de sorteos donde se registran hasta 5 números. La tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
Primeiro | Segundo | Terceiro | Quarto | Quinto
```

Cada campo toma un número aleatorio. Ejemplo:

```
Primero | Segundo | Tercera | Cuatro | Quinto 
  11         15        20       23       25
```

Me gustaría crear números aleatorios, pero diferentes a los números ya sorteados. Probé de la siguiente manera, pero no funcionó ya que solo me trajo 2322 secuencias.

```
<?php
 $sqlR = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM sorteios_lf");
 while($foxR = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlR)){               
          $sqlContar = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT * FROM sorteios_lf 
                                         WHERE Primeiro <> '".$foxR->Primeiro."'
                                                 AND Segundo <> '".$foxR->Segundo."'
                                                 AND Terceiro <> '".$foxR->Terceiro."'
                                                 AND Quarto <> '".$foxR->Quarto."'
                                                 AND Quinto <> '".$foxR->Quinto.";");                                                    
           $contar = (mysqli_num_rows($sqlContar) > 1) ? '<span style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">'.mysqli_num_rows($sqlContar).'</span>' : mysqli_num_rows($sqlContar);                                                         
          // $texto = "<span style='font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;'>Existem <strong>".$contar."</strong> combinações disponíveis!</span>";
           if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlContar) > 0){ 
              echo '<span style="font-weight: bold; ">'.$cc.' - </span>';
           ?>                            
                              <?php if($foxR->Primeiro < 10) echo '0'.$foxR->Primeiro; else echo $foxR->Primeiro; ?>, 
                              <?php if($foxR->Segundo < 10) echo '0'.$foxR->Segundo; else echo $foxR->Segundo; ?>, 
                              <?php if($foxR->Terceiro < 10) echo '0'.$foxR->Terceiro; else echo $foxR->Terceiro; ?>, 
                              <?php if($foxR->Quarto < 10) echo '0'.$foxR->Quarto; else echo $foxR->Quarto; ?>, 
                              <?php if($foxR->Quinto < 10) echo '0'.$foxR->Quinto; else echo $foxR->Quinto; ?>
                      <br>
 <?php          
            }
?>
```

Lo siento por mi español.

Comment: ¿los números de cada campo van del 0 al 99? ¿del 1 al 99? ¿del 1 al infinito?

Comment: de donde sale el 2232 que nombras? donde generas las secuencias?

Comment: ¿los números no pueden repetirse dentro de cada sorteo entre sus campos? ¿o en todos los sorteos? ¿y porque usas mysql para eso? Con una función recursiva en PHP no te haria falta el mysql para nada, aparte que así vas a reventar al servidor de base de datos.

Comment: Hola te recomiendo que agregues un estatus activo en tu tabla luego cuando se ejecute el código PHP haciendo un where igual a estatus activo abajo de lo que ya tienes hagas un update estatus inactivo.  Pero que en adelante ya no te tome los números que ya se tomaron.

Comment: Hola maestrogurú. Hice un ajuste en mi publicación. Los números van del 1 al 25.

Comment: Hola gbianchi. Este número es la cantidad total cuando ejecuto la consulta de publicación.

Comment: Hola maestrogurú. Eso. Los números no se pueden repetir. En php y Mysql, primero saqué todos los números y dentro del bucle creé este filtro, generándome los números que aún no me salen del 1 al 25. Pero creo que lo hice mal :(

Comment: Hola Henrique10. De hecho, las combinaciones no se pueden repetir, así que no creé el estatus.

Comment: A ver, si tu pregunta es: **¿Cuantas combinaciones de 5 elementos con 25 números, que no pueden repetirse _nunca_, tanto entre los 5 elementos como en la siguiente combinación, pueden realizarse?**  La respuesta es **5**. Pero si la pregunta es: **¿Cuantas combinaciones de 5 elementos con 25 números que no pueden repetirse nunca entre los 5 elementos, pero sí en la siguiente combinación, sin repetir combinaciones, pueden realizarse?** entonces la respuesta es una burrada, y es un problema de combinatoria clásico que se resuelve con su fórmula matemática, y dudo que quieras mostrarlos todos.

Comment: Hola maestro gurú. Perdón. No puedes entender bien tu pregunta. El sistema de sorteos es para una empresa, donde quincenalmente realizará sorteos para los empleados. Lo que quiere hacer es mostrarles opciones diarias de números que aún no han salido para que puedan usar las nuevas combinaciones o hacer sus propias combinaciones. El sistema de sorteo está listo, solo falta esta parte. Creo que esto se puede resolver directamente por SQL, sin necesidad de una solución matemática, ¿no?